# Converting custom fields assigned to orders into read-only or disabled fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have created a few custom fields for my Woocommerce orders using [WooCommerce Admin Custom Order Fields](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-admin-custom-order-fields/). I'm only creating orders manually on the admin side. Is it possible to make one of these fields read-only/disabled? I'm already populating the value of it in the code, so I don't want the user to be able to write in that field.

[image]

Comment: This can be done only if you don't use this plugin to generate your custom fields… Using this plugin avoid coding yourself those fields, but gives some limitations too…

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a custom script that runs on the admin side to make the field read-only using jQuery.